# When you update XCode, does it automatically update the sdks for your projects?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I'm trying to test my apps on my phone, but my phone is running iOS 8.2, and the sdks on my apps are 8.1

If I update my XCode, will it update the SDK of my app automatically?

Comment: So I would have to update the SDK in my apps to have them run on my phone, how would I go about that? As I understand it, I would have to update my XCode to support ios 8.2, then download the ios 8.2 sdk?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the App Store page for Xcode 6.2 it says it includes SDKs for iOS 8.2. So you can re-build your app once you have the new Xcode.

I don't think I have ever needed to manually add SDKs for the latest iOS.  I have had to add an SDK when I want to support an older version - like supporting iOS 7 with a new version of Xcode.